# PHP readfile() how to handle return value

Tags: php, return-value, readfile

I'm learning PHP so this is the question for education purposes. Since I can't find an answer in tutorials I use, would be nice from you to make it clear for me.

So, imagine we have a file "text.txt" and content is:

```
"Hello World!"
```

The following PHP script:

```
<?php

echo readfile("text.txt");

?>
```

Will output "Hello World!12" - I can't think of any cases when such an output can be useful, but I found that if I don't want to see the file length at the end, I've to omit "echo":

```
<?php

readfile("text.txt");

?>
```

The output will be "Hello World!". This is a way better, but manual says: "Returns the number of bytes read from the file.", so my question is - How am I supposed to get the file length using the readfile() function? According to my logic it "returns" the file content but I feel like I didn't get something right. Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: uhm, can't you use `filesize("text.txt");` ?

Comment: @Farkie Thank you for your comment. Sure I can, and it works. But as I said I'm trying to learn PHP, so that I would be happy to understand how the things work, and since the manual says readfile() returns the number of bytes, I'm trying to figure out how to use it right.

Comment: @Mike  filesize($file) will return the size of the file in bytes (int). Please check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: .. I already said that, @MilosM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to read the size of a file using `readfile()`? Sure, but this function also outputs the file. No biggie, we have something we can use in this situation: `output buffering`.

```
<?php

ob_start();
$length = readfile("text.txt");
// the content of the file isn't lost as well, and you can manipulate it
$content = ob_get_clean();

echo $length;

?>
```

Comment: Oh I see, but why do we need a function that returns 2 values at a time "content+filesize"? Yes, I read people say "It outputs the content and returns a value", but we don't have a way to obtain the return value without preventing the output?

Comment: Well, there are many different ways to do different things. This method is actually good for outputting large files as it doesn't hold it into memory. I guess it returns the length for _reasons_ that are unknown!

Answer (score 1):

`readfile` is not used to get file size or file content the way you write. It is typically used to send a file to the client. For example, suppose that you have created a pdf file in your web application after the client submit a form or clicked some link. Sometimes you can direct them to the file directly, but sometimes you dont want that for some reasons(security etc.). This way you can do this:

How it is ment to be used.

```
    $filepath = "../files/test.pdf";

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='test.pdf'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
    readfile($filepath);
    exit;
```

An example for which you may use it.

```
    $filepath = "../files/test.pdf";

    ob_start();
    $filesize = readfile($filepath);
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='test.pdf'");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . $filesize );

    echo $content;

    exit;
```

So, here you output the file content in addition to the correct headers so that the browser will identify it as a pdf file and open it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you explain please why do we ever need "return value" of the readfile() function and how can we use it?

Comment: You could use the file size from the `readfile`s returned value and avoid calling `filesize`. Just buffer the content.

Comment: As @MujnoiGyulaTamas mentioned, you can use this not to call another filesize as I did write in the post. You could use the return value of readfile instead of filesize, so you can get rid of one more call although it is not really expensive.

Comment: @abeyaz Thank you for your explanations, I really appreciate your help. But I hope you will agree with me, that the answer accept goes to Farkie since he was first and provided the actual way of getting filesize when using readfile() function.

Comment: Wait for the edited version as well to fully understand the concept. It's a mix of the 2 answears :)

Comment: Isn't using of ob_start() and ob_get_clean() more expensive than calling filesize() once? Just curious.

Comment: Can be. I never use it this way actually. I always prefer filesize in addition to readfile. Because, this way you use more memory. That is why using return value of readfile is useless. But I approved the edit, coz you wanted to know.

Comment: Well you will have a performance loss, since you're capturing in memory the contents of the file, as opposed to what the `readfile` is actually ment for. So it's basically the same as `file_get_contents`. You won't actually us this example in a real world application. LE: I mean the edited version.

Comment: One thing that comes in my mind is that after you outputed the file and before the exit maybe you wan't to do some operation with the file length?

Comment: Thank you guys! Well it's valuable to hear from people who have an actual experience. Now I have both, understanding the way it works as described and the way it's actually used. :)

Comment: @Mike I have requested another edit, which I should have made in the first place.  To actually have the 2 examples side by side

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas Thank you very much, now it's very descriptive! You have a talent with edits to make things perfect!